# Single test method for large data set

Tags: c#, testing

I have written a test case with `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`, iterating through a large number of test cases which are stored in a text file on disk. As soon as one of the test cases causes the "unit test" to fail, the Assert method I am using (`AreEqual` or `Fail`) returns an `ErrorMessage` containing the details of the failed case. This is great, however, I want my code to continue executing all test cases even if there is one case which fails, so I can see the details of all failing cases.

I understand from my research that this is not necessarily a unit test as per the definition in [Unit testing large data sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235402/unit-testing-large-data-sets) so I am also open to alternative suggestions on how to solve this problem, not just those related to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` or a unit testing framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a concept called [Data Driven Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_testing). I've used it in NUnit, but there is a way of [doing it in Visual Studio Unit testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx) as well.

This creates one test per data row, as opposed to a single test for entire dataset. This will run the test for your entire dataset and continue to next data item even on failure. The end result will highlight failure and success treating each test case individually.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. I just got it working using a CSV file as a data source. I can now see the detail of 73 of my tests run in one hit. Brilliant! The only disappointment: I just discovered NCrunch doesn't support MSTest data driven tests...

Comment: Yeah - there seems to be a topic on NCrunch-Mstest data driven test in [NCrunch Forums](http://forum.ncrunch.net/yaf_postst180_ETA-of-MSTest-data-driven-tests.aspx). Tough luck. I am guessing you have scripts that run the tests, in which case you should get these covered as well.

Answer (score 3):

Something I have done in the past is to create a [t4](/questions/tagged/t4) template to create my tests from a data source. Usually a CSV file of the tests. To (re)generate all you need to do is open the TT file and save it to regenerate - or use the VS tooling.

This has the advantage of having only one test for each condition, and it will also give you easily repeatable tests, even though they are generated for you. You can also debug failing tests very easily because the code is C# at the end of the day.

For example create a *.tt with this content and have a CSV file with some data:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".generated.cs" #>
<#
    var testCases =
        File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(Host.TemplateFile, @"Cases.csv"))
        .Skip(1)  //Headers
        .Select(line => line.Split(','))
        .Select(
            values =>
                new
                {
                    TestName = values[0],
                    Expected = values[1],
                    Actual = values[2],
                    //More Stuff from values[n]
                });
#>
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace DaveShaw
{
    [TestClass]
    public class GeneratedTests
    {
<#
    foreach (var testCase in testCases)
    {
#>
        [TestMethod]
        public void Generated_<#= testCase.Name #>()
        {
            //Put your Arrange & Act code here
            Assert.AreEqual(
                expected: <#= testCase.Expected #>
                actual: <#= testCase.Expected #>);
        }
<#
    }
#>
    }
}
```

When you save you will have a *.generated.cs (where * is the same as the *.tt) with all your tests in there.